# Rename Pandas column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe like this

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | c |
| 5 | d |

I want to name the column 2 as:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row1 |
| 2 | row1 |
| 3 | row2 |
| 4 | row3 |
| 5 | row4 |

I am trying the ways that are hard coded, like renaming each column, but in practice I have lots of rows so hard coding is not possible, is there any function or something python that can do the same task for me?

Comment: like a replace? whole df ->  df.replace(['a'],row1,inplace=True) or by column df['column name'].replace([a'], 'row1') ; more at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try [`Series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html#pandas.Series.factorize)

```py
df['Column2'] = (pd.Series(df['Column2'].factorize()[0])
                 .add(1).astype(str).radd('row'))
```

```
print(df)

   Column1 Column2
0        1    row1
1        2    row1
2        3    row2
3        4    row3
4        5    row4
```